# What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: c#, algorithm, division

My problem is the answer of this code. I know it's working but the answer is taking so long and the numbers still going.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long Number = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            if (Number % i != 0)
            {
                i = 1;
                Number++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Number);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I want the console write the last number but i dont know what to do.

Comment: Debug your code and inspect the value of `i` in each iteration of your `for` loop, you will see the problem pretty fast I think. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: The answer is slightly above 232 million, so you have some way to go (and I got there by just using a calculator)

Comment: 99% of your computer's efforts are writing to the console on every iteration.  If you wrap your `Console.WriteLine` with an if like `if (Number % 10000 == 0)`, you'll get to your answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Or just move that Console.WriteLine to just *after* the loop - then it took my PC 3.5 seconds to display the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(problem().ToString());

}

    public static int problem()
            {
                int i =1;
                bool found = false;
                while (!found)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    bool isDividable = true;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
                    {
                        if (i % j != 0)
                        {
                            isDividable = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isDividable)
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                return i;
            }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the answer is

```
5 * 7 * 9 * 11 * 13 * 16 * 17 * 19 == 232792560
```

So in case of *brute force* we should be quite fast (`~2e8` loops):

```
for (int number = 1; ; ++number) {
  // we assume number is the answer, and check it
  bool found = true;

  for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= 20; ++divisor) {
    if (number % divisor != 0) {
      found = false; // counter example found...

      break;
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    Console.WriteLine(number);

    break;
  } 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TCTFlp)

Comment: sir can u pls help me Euler project Number 4

Comment: @Mo R: it seems that *brute force* will be the easiest approach: you have to u=inspect `900 * 900 = 810000` numbers only (https://dotnetfiddle.net/ogOWbR). **906609**